# make a matrix with permutations of Range of numbers in Mathematica 9

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, permutation

I start learning Mathematica 9. I need to make a nx4 matrix "m" with permutations of Range of numbers, where first column is matrix "A" and second, third, fourth columns are matrix "B". Moreover, I need to exclude the first row. Can anybody help me?

```
`t = 2; a = Range[0, t]; b = Range[0, t]; c = Range[0, t];
{A = MatrixForm[
   1/Sqrt[Flatten[
      Table[a^2 + b^2 + c^2, {a, 0, t, 1}, {b, 0, t, 1}, {c, 0, t, 
        1}]]]],
 B = MatrixForm[Tuples[{a, b, c}]]}`
```

I need something like this:

```
List[List[0, 0, 1, 1], List[0, 0, 2, Rational[1, 4]], 
 List[0, 1, 0, 1], List[0, 1, 1, Rational[1, 2]], 
 List[0, 1, 2, Rational[1, 5]], List[0, 2, 0, Rational[1, 4]], 
 List[0, 2, 1, Rational[1, 5]], List[0, 2, 2, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[1, 0, 0, \[Placeholder]], List[1, 0, 1, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[1, 0, 2, \[Placeholder]], List[1, 1, 0, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[1, 1, 1, \[Placeholder]], List[1, 1, 2, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[1, 2, 0, \[Placeholder]], List[1, 2, 1, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[1, 2, 2, \[Placeholder]], List[2, 0, 0, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[2, 0, 1, \[Placeholder]], List[2, 0, 2, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[2, 1, 0, \[Placeholder]], List[2, 1, 1, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[2, 1, 2, \[Placeholder]], List[2, 2, 0, \[Placeholder]], 
 List[2, 2, 1, \[Placeholder]], List[2, 2, 2, \[Placeholder]]]
```

This is what I want to do in Mathematica [made in MathCad](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By3qYPAc-Upna21BTG9xUW9TeUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Before turning to a solution to your problem I can see a couple of issues with your code that you, as a beginner, ought to be aware of and avoid in future:

- You have wrapped the evaluations `A =` and `B =` inside a pair of `{}` so that the result will be a list comprising the two expressions resulting from the evaluations. This won't create a matrix, it will create a list containing two `MatrixForm`s.
- It's generally a bad idea to wrap an expression inside `MatrixForm[]` and assign it to a variable.  `MatrixForm[]` is really intended for making outputs look nice, most operations which work on Mathematica lists (and arrays and matrices are just lists of lists) won't work on objects with head `MatrixForm[]`.
- Evaluating your expression which starts `1/Sqrt[Flatten[` generates an error message: `Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered."` when `a==0,b==0,c==0`.

Finally, some advice you haven't asked for: using variable names which differ only in the case of their letters, as you do with `A` and `a` and with `B` and `b`, is a sure route to a world of pain and desperation. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

**EDIT**

You can easily generate the first 3 columns of your result with the command:

```
Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3]
```

Now this includes the element `{0,0,0}` so we'll drop it, like this

```
Drop[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3],1]
```

and now calculate the 4th column with a replacement rule, like this:

```
Drop[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], 1] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z, 1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}
```

Note that I haven't assigned the result of this expression to be the value of any variable, you may want to.  Note too that I haven't created any intermediate variables, this keeps your workspace (in Mathematica-speak `Context`) nice and tidy.